# Regresion Lineal y calculo del R2 para variable cualitativa vs cuantitatva

Tags: python, python-3.x

Deseo realizar una regresión lineal en un set de datos de un inventario de deslizamientos. Cada evento posee un área en metros cuadrados (La variable cuantitativa de mi interés) y tipo de movimiento.

La solución que tengo consiste en generar tantas variables independientes como categorías haya en la variable cualitativa, y a continuación codificar cada una de estas variables con “ceros” y “unos” según la categoría a la que pertenezca los distintos sujetos. Una vez hecho esto, importo los datos a excel y realizo la regresión lineal. El codigo que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

nombreFichero='muestra.csv'
Data= pd.read_csv(nombreFichero, header = 0, sep=None,  engine='python')
muestra= pd.DataFrame(Data)

Rotacional= []
Traslacional= []
Sin_catalogar= []

def subtipo(lista):
    for i in lista:
        if i== 'Rotacional':
            Rotacional.append(1), Traslacional.append(0), Sin_catalogar.append(0)
        elif i== 'Traslacional':
            Rotacional.append(0), Traslacional.append(1), Sin_catalogar.append(0)
        elif i== 'Sin catalogar':
            Rotacional.append(0), Traslacional.append(0), Sin_catalogar.append(1)

a= muestra['Subtipo'].tolist()
subtipo(a)

muestra['Rotacional']= pd.DataFrame(Rotacional)                 
muestra['Traslacional']= pd.DataFrame(Traslacional)   
muestra['Sin catalogar']=  pd.DataFrame(Sin_catalogar)
muestra.to_csv('muestra.csv')
muestra.head()
```

[image: El resultado es el esperado]

Aunque tenga lo que quiero, se me hace muy impráctico este proceso, a sabiendas que entre más categorias tenga la variable, más extenso sera el código (Por ejemplo la variable Nombre_c_1 tiene 11 categorías).

Dejo el link de los datos:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_2kvV08fTHgBUY03NsHa0zph1cbnhkUEfb1OnZX9Ono/edit#gid=0

Habra alguna forma de optimizar el código para poder calcular el R2 entre la variable cuantitativa y la cualitativa?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que estás tratando de hacer se llama one-hot encoding, para futuras referencias.

Ahora, no es necesario que construyas tu mismo la función que hará esta separación de una variable `cualitativa` en varios vectores con `1` en la categoria que te interesa y `0` en las demás.

El mismo `pandas` ya tiene esta funcionalidad, al ser bastante común.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.get_dummies(muestra.Clas_slp_1)
```

Te dejo esta [guía](http://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html) donde encuentras múltiples ejemplos.